# Reacting to Webrequest while answering it - Python 3.7

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, webserver

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can host a simple webserver to handle POST requests with Python 3.7. My problem is that I want to answer requests after they were received, but the submitted POST data should be used to play back a specific audio file on my RaspberryPi. In two days of googling I couldn't figure out how to have the webserver run constantly while processing the incoming requests in the background.

I tried to use the subprocess module to run the playback script in the background but I never found a way to have it run in the background independently from the webserver. I always end up with my webserver getting a request which is than handled, but while this happens the webserver is unaccessible.

I would apreciate if someone pointed out a direction to look at for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I always end up with my webserver getting a request which is than handled, but while this happens the webserver is unaccessible.

To solve this problem, you can create a separate `thread` or a `process` to handle the request while the main thread/process goes back to processing new requests.

The workflow will be something like this:

1. The `main process` receives a request
2. The `main process` creates a `new process` to handle the request.
3. The `main process` goes back to listening for new requests while the `new process` processes the received request.

Assuming, you are unfamiliar with `multithreading` and `multiprocessing`, I'd suggest you go read a little about these topics. Most likely, `multithreading` will solve your problem. So, you can start from there. Here's a good article about it: [An Intro to Threading in Python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)